# Modeling a digital circuit using metaprogramming

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I am struggling to model a simple digital circuit system using metaprogramming.

The idea is add class methods (such as 'input', 'output') to Circuit class. Each new circuit modeled (let's say Adder for instance) inherits Circuit. When instantiating such a circuit, I should be able to access its inputs by its name and get the corresponding object (an Input instance). Let's exemplify that:

```
class Input
  attr_accessor :name, :value
  def initialize name
    @name = name
    @value=nil
  end
end

class Circuit
  def self.input name
    send(:attr_accessor, name)
    var_name = "@#{name}"
    self.instance_variable_set(var_name, Input.new(name)) #no effect...
  end
end

class Adder < Circuit
  input :a
  input :b
  # output :f
end

p adder = Adder.new
p adder.a #Should be an Input instance, whose name attribute is :a
```

So far, I just managed to dynamically add the correct accessor for the named port.

Should I use class_eval, instance_eval, or define_method?

Comment: You can't. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `instance_variable_set` on the wrong object. You're doing it on a class itself, when it should be done on new instances of that class.

Something like this:

```
class Circuit
  def self.input(name)
    send(:attr_accessor, name)

    # take note of this new input, we'll use it later
    @_inputs ||= []
    @_inputs << name
  end

  def initialize
    # instantiate all defined inputs

    self.class.instance_variable_get(:@_inputs).each do |name|
      send("#{name}=", Input.new(name))
    end
  end
end

class Adder < Circuit
  input :a
  input :b
end

t = Adder.new
t.a # => #<Input:0x007f9664077ea0 @name=:a, @value=nil>
```